# Numpy. Multiply multiple arrays to make 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

Given my nested for loops that computes an array as shown, how can I write this out in Numpy without using any loops?

```
for i in range(self.output):
        for j in range(self.input):
            for k in range(self.hidden):

                #self.delta_wh[i, j, k] = -self.output_deltas[i]*self.wo[k, i] * self.dsigneth[k] * self.outi[j]
```

Comment: Also, it would be useful if you could provide a minimum set of data and expected result.

Comment: There is no summing going on in this for loop though. How would taking the dot product anywhere here help?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the job can be done by `np.ix_` Only `wo` requires some manual work. I've shortened your variable names a bit:

```
>>> import numpy as np

# sizes 
>>> i, j ,k = 2, 3, 4

# fake data
>>> od = np.arange(i)
>>> wo = np.arange(k*i).reshape(k, i)
>>> ds = np.arange(k)
>>> ou = np.arange(j)

# prepare for broadcasting
>>> OD, OU, DS = np.ix_(od, ou, ds)
>>> WO = wo.T[:, None, :]

# now the shapes are:
# OD  --  (i, 1, 1)
# OU  --  (1, j, 1)
# DS  --  (1, 1, k)
# WO  --  (i, 1, k)

# do the calculation and check shape
>>> (-OD*WO*DS*OU).shape
(2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version (prepend `self.` to array names):

```
delta_wh = -(output_deltas * wo).T[:,None,:]*np.outer(dsigneth, outi).T[None,:,:]
```

or, using @PaulPanzer's notation:

```
delta_wh = -(od * wo).T[:,None,:]*np.outer(ds, ou).T[None,:,:]
```